# How to change the link in an active button dependent upon a variable

Tags: javascript

My web page is divided into day reports. As many as 25 per page. I have created a js array where I enter the titles for each day.  For each day, a script runs that displays the appropriate title for that day.

Each day also has a button that a person can click and link to a google map for that day.

The button is formed by the following js and XXX is the link:-

```
document.write('<table id="vista-buttons_com_idkli11" width="0" cellpadding="0"
cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td style="padding-right:0px" title ="View Map"><a 
href="XXX" onmouseover=\'xpe("kli11o");\' onmouseout=\'xpe("kli11n");\' 
class="mapbutton"><img id="xpi_kli11" src="'+vbImgPath+'/btkli11_0.gif" name="vbkli11" 
width="197" height="66" border="0" alt="View Map" /></a></td></tr></table>');

vbkli11n=xppr('kli11_0.gif');
vbkli11o=xppr('kli11_1.gif');
var btIdPref="vb";

function xppr(im){
    var i=new Image;
    i.src=vbImgPath+"bt"+im;return i;
}

function xpe(id){
    x=id.substring(0,id.length-1);
    if(document[btIdPref+x]){
        document[btIdPref+x].src=eval(btIdPref+id+".src");
    }
}
```

If I create another array of the required links similar to:

```
var link=new Array();
link[1]="http://g.co/maps/8ppb8"; 
link[2]="etc...
```

how can I get the button's js to use the link?

(And please don't tell me I should be using a database for this).

Hope this is clear.

Steve

Comment: document.write? nonsensy function names? ugh.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
    window.location
```

For example:

```
    onclick="window.loaction = 'XXX'"
```

I hope that's clear enough. If not I can edit if you need more information.

**EDIT:**
After reading the comments I hope this example helps you out:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript">
link = ['http://www.google.com', 'http://www.stackoverflow.com', 'http://www.bing.com']
function changeLocation(index) {
    window.location = link[index]
}
</script>
</head>
<body >
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a onclick="changeLocation(0)">Google</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a onclick="changeLocation(1)">Stackoverflow</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a onclick="changeLocation(2)">Bing</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: Hm.  All this does is display window.loaction='xxx'.  Further I need the xxx to change dependent upon the link in the array  So if it is day 6 the script needs to use the link texxt applicable to that day.

Comment: Sorry it's quite difficult to understand. Also I made a little typo. I fixed it in the edit. So what you're saying is that, XXX is a certain link und you want to put all those links in the array `link`? I think it would be easier to help you if you added more information to your original post.

Comment: I have an array link[1] link[2] link[3] etc  I want to reference the link[] etc from the js script. So that when the day changes to day 2 say, then the script uses the link stored at array ref [2]